# Multiple Layers in Canvas with React

Tags: canvas

I try to use canvas, such that I can move a rectangle over an image, but I don't get how I can use two Layers to achieve this? I have seen that one can use z-index, but this seems not to work with react. The problem is, that the image and the moving rectangle are next to each other, and not on top of each other. How can I make, that the layers are on top of each other?

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './../css/index.css'

var img;
var ctx;
var ctx2;
var canvas;
var canvas2;
var color;
var coordinates;

var rectSize = {
  color: '#666',
  dim: { w: 20, h: 20 },
};

class App extends React.Component {


   constructor(props){
      super(props)

      window.a = this.state
   }

   componentDidMount(){
      this.SetImage();
   }


   SetImage() {
    img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.src = testImgPath;
    canvas = this.canvas1;
    canvas2 = this.canvas2;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      img.style.display = 'none';
    };
    color = this.color1;
    coordinates = this.coordinates1;

    function pick(event) {
      var x = event.layerX;
      var y = event.layerY;
      var pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
      var data = pixel.data;
      var rgba = 'rgba(' + data[0] + ', ' + data[1] +
                 ', ' + data[2] + ', ' + (data[3] / 255) + ')';
      var coord = '(x: ' +  x  + ', y: ' + y + ')';
      //color.style.background =  rgba;
      color.textContent = rgba;
      coordinates.textContent = coord;

      ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
      ctx2.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx2.fillRect(x, y, rectSize.dim.w, rectSize.dim.h);
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', pick);    
   }

   render(){
      return (
         <div className="main-container">            
            <div styles="position:relative">
              <canvas id="canvas1" ref={(ref) => this.canvas1 = ref} width="500" height="500" styles="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;"/>
              <canvas id="canvas2" ref={(ref) => this.canvas2 = ref} width="500" height="500" styles="z-index: 2; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;"/>  
            </div>   

         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
              <canvas id="canvas1" ref={(ref) => this.canvas1 = ref} width="500" height="500" styles="z-index: 1; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;"/>
```

should become

```
          <canvas id="canvas1" ref={(ref) => this.canvas1 = ref} width="500" height="500" style={{zIndex:1, position: absolute, top: 0, left: 0}}/>
```

Comment: I get the error, that absolute is not defined, so this seems not to work either. Also when I remove the absolute argument, the rectangle is stil next to the image.

Comment: sorry, it should be string, i.e. `'absolute'`

Comment: When I put this in, then I don't see any rectangle anymore. I think it does not find the position of the canvas anymore

Comment: I suppose you should add `bottom: 0, right; 0` to the styles object. It's not a react issue, but styles  however!

Comment: Also, in order to order to use position: absolute, if I am not mistaken the parent container should have `position: relative`

Comment: I implemented my example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/y2l9yyr92z - it seems still not to work when i want one canvas above the other. The basic implementation is as yours, but then I use the callbacks, and there it seems to fail somehow.

Comment: Here is an example how it looks actually: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9p84984qo - I want the red rectangle on top of the black box. Immediately if I include the absolute position, it somehow does not recognize my mouse movement anymore

Comment: Hi. You've lost the `position: absolute` for canvases on the way :-)

Comment: Ye, because then it seems not to work. It somehow then does not recognize mousevents